# How to find persons participating in all the films

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-division

I can't formulate the following queries to save my life:

Who participated in all films, which film was shown in all cinemas, which cinemas show all films?

Given the following relations:

```
film: [ID, title, year, genre]
person: [ID, name, firstname]
cinema: [ID, name, city]
participation: [film, person, function ('actor', or 'director')]
show: [film, date, cinema]
```

Where film, person, and cinema are foreign keys in `Participation` and `Show`.

I'm also not sure if the ALL keyword is required, or if it can be done without it.

Comment: what queries?  That might help.

Comment: That's the thing, i can't formulate them, I can only ask them:
Who participated in all films? Which film was shown in all cinemas? Which cinemas show all films?

Comment: Ah....  ok then let me suggest an edit.

Comment: is that edit helpful?

Comment: Yes, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

who participated in al films?

```
select person_id,count(*) as c 
from participation 
group by person_id 
having c = (select count(*) from film)
```

You should be ok to get the rest now since it's the same procedure.

I did a little fiddle to try it: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/795a34/1)

Comment: Thank you for the sqlfiddle link! I didn't know such a resource existed!

Answer (score 0):

> **How to find persons participating in all the films**

One method is to count, for each person, a number of films that this person participaded in, and then compare with a total number of films

```
SELECT person_id
FROM participation
GROUP BY person_id
HAVING count( distinct film_id ) = (
          SELECT count(*) FROM film
)
```

Answer (score 0):

These can be solved with sub-queries:

1) **Who participated in all films**

```
Select ID
From person as P1
where not exists
   (select distinct id
    from film
    difference
    select distinct film_id
    from participation as P2
    where P2.person_Id = P1.Id)
```

The subquery finds all movies in which the person participates, and takes the difference with all movies. If the person participates in all, then the result will be an empty set. The outer query finds that persons participate in all movies by checking that the subquery returns an empty set.

The pattern can be used to answers the other queries.

Comment: Thank you Manuel, this is more like what my classmate said to, can you explain the reason behind the not exits and why it works?
For the question "which film was shown in all cinemas" I got something like this:
    
    SELECT: title
    FROM: film
    WHERE: not exists(SELECT: * FROM: cinema WHERE not exists(SELECT: * FROM: show WHERE: cinema.ID = cinema AND film.ID = film)